# Why to use SpringKafka Template in place existing Kafka Producer Consumer api?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

What benefits does spring Kafka template provide?

I have tried the existing Producer/Consumer API by Kafka. That is very simple to use, then why use Kafka template.

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Template internally uses Kafka producer so you can directly use Kafka APIs. The benefit of using Kafka template is it provides different methods for sending message to Kafka topic, kind of added benefits you can see the API comparison between `KafkaProducer` and `KafkaTemplate` here:

https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/core/KafkaTemplate.html

You can see `KafkaTemplate` provide many additional ways of sending data to Kafka topics because of various `send` methods while some calls are the same as Kafka API and are simply forwarded from `KafkaTemplate` to `KafkaProducer`.

It's up to the developer what to use. If you feel like working with `KafkaTemplate` is easy as you don't have to create `ProducerRecord` a simple `send` method will do all the work for you.

Comment: I appreciate the differences you have highlighted and understand the benefits of using spring. But we are still on spring 4.x and spring-kafka using spring 5 and say we don't want dependency on spring for kafka(only). So only thing i would need to do is to create a singleton object boiler plate code for Producer. Can you highlight some major reason for using spring-kaka?

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, the benefit is that you can externalize your properties objects more easily and you can just focus on the record processing logic

Plus Spring is integrated with lots of other components.

Note: Other options still exist like Reactor Kafka, Alpakka, Apache Camel, Smallrye reactive messaging, Vert.x... But they all wrap the same Kafka API.

So, I'd say you're (marginally) trading efficiency for convinience